# Can You Identify This Deep Groove Ball Baring Bearing and/or Give an SKF Equivalent?

Tags: automotive-engineering, bearings

I am changing out my motorcycle engine bearings from the Chinese CJB brand to a high quality brand like SKF (Explorer range).

I am still waiting on a heat gun in order to remove the bearings from the engine case, and one bearing has been installed with it's codes facing into the blind seat.

1. I do know that its dimensions are 17x47x14mm, so it's a 6303 series.
2. All of the other bearings have a C3 fit, so I assume this will as well.
3. The other bearings all use PA66 or Glass-Fibre Reinforced PA66 cages, but they look quite different to this cage.
4. All other bearings are Class 6 Precision, so I am assuming this is as well.

Can anyone recognise the type of cage in this bearing? Do you know an SKF-equivalent suffix or prefix, or any brand's suffix that matches it?

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Thank you,

Nicholas

[image]

Comment: Try the SKF catalogues.

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike, I spent a lot of time looking through it before asking this question. I was able to identify all the other like-for-like bearings but this one.

Comment: If you're replacing this bearing with no intention of reusing it you can just pry it out with a screw driver, or at least remove the cage in that manner. FWIW any DGBB manufactured to the same clearance and tolerance will operate nearly identical. There's not really a need to change them out for "name brand" pieces unless you're not sure of the OEM quality. Even if it says they're "made" in another country they're typically just assembled there with the races, elements and cages all imported from China anyway.

Comment: Thanks for that jko. I'm hoping/expecting to find the part number on the other side once I remove it from the seat. Was just hoping to be able to "get ahead of the game" and put an early order in - you never know wait times, especially in these times. I have to give credit where credit is due, because these bearings have lasted over 110,000 kms in my bike so far.

Comment: The strange thing is, if I buy them again from BMW, they will cost 2-3 times that of a name brand like SKF or F.A.G. I'm hoping not to have to look at the inside of my engine case for another 100k kms, so I may as well go with something that makes me feel content, even if there turns out to be little difference. Thanks again.

Comment: You'll get the best prices from distributors for a part like that since they buy in bulk from the manufacturer. My go to in the US is McMaster-Carr, I'm not sure what equivalent there might be where you are. DGBB are surprisingly simple to manufacture, I used to work for a large bearing company and machines would spit out 6000 series pieces all day.

Comment: Doing a little more searching, and I am starting to think that this may actually be an Angular Contact Ball Bearing. There are no SKF DGBB in this dimension with a cage that resembles that in the picture. The closest looking cage in the DGBB range is for a double-row DGBB, but then that isn't made in these dimensions.

Comment: It sort of makes sense, as this is the only bearing in the engine that is installed in a blind seat. The Compensating Shaft (one of the two gearbox shafts) spins in this bearing. I imagine that there is some axial thrust in this shaft as I move up and down the gears, and the Angular Contact Ball Bearing is designed for both radial and axial loads.

Comment: As this is not a matched or back-to-back bearing, it looks llike it might be an SKF 7303BEP bearing. B=40 degrees contact, E = Optimised Internal Deisgn, P = Glass fibre reinforced PA66 cage, ball centred. It's starting to look like some of my initial assumptions regarding it being a 63 series and a C3 fit may have been wrong. Ass u me. I'll leave a comment here when I resolve this (I hate unresolved or unfinished posts).

Comment: Just to round out this post: I have removed the bearing and it turned out to be a Deep Groove Ball Bearing with the following designation from CJB manufacturer: TM6303YA1 -RS1TN. So I know which way to proceed now. Thanks to those who helped.